# Pause Dropbox after sync

Tags: scripts, 20.04, sync, dropbox

Is is possible to automatically pause dropbox after sync? I am thinking, every time I start my computer, dropbox is also starting. But, is it possible to get Dropbox to pause or close directly after sync is done? Maye with a script.

Answer (score 0):

click the dropbox menu in the menu bar of your computer, click your profile picture, click pause syncing or resume syncing. hope that helps!